# How to filter content in Dashboard?

Tags: filters

I want to modify the post content, before it is shown in dashboard "EDITOR" page..
Is there any available hook/filter for it?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions seems to be (found in `/wp-includes/class-wp-editor`):

```
add_filter('the_editor_content', 'YourFunctionName');
```